# Can Dijkstra's algorithm be exponential?

Tags: algorithms, network

> Teacher say:  Given a directed a-cyclic graph $G = (V , E)$, with
> negative edges weights, now We can claim that, Dijkstra's relaxation
> function do $\Omega(2^n)$ relaxation  edges, but every times i think,
> i get stuck to prove it. In addition, I found reference of  This problem come from "Jeff
> Erickson, Algorithms text book".

Anyone can give me a hint to construct an example to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard implementation of Dijkstra does not work with negative edge weights. This is due to its greedy nature. Here is an example:

Consider the directed graph $G=(V,E)$ with $E=\{(a,b, 4), (a, c, 2), (b, c, -3)\}$ and assume that we want to find the shortest path from $a$ to $c$.
Dijkstra's algorithm will extract vertex $c$ from the queue before it will extract $b$ and report $2$ as the shortest path from $a$ to $c$. But the correct answer would have been $1$ ($a \to b$, $b \to c$).

However, if we restrict $G$ to the acyclic case, we can make Dijsktra’s algorithm work for negative weights but we must allow visiting vertices more than once (meaning, we do not mark vertex $c$ as closed).

However, this leads to calculating each possible path from $a$ to $c$ and in the worst case there are $2^{n-2}$ possible paths in a directed acyclic graph on $n$ vertices (checkout [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284700/maximum-number-of-path-for-acyclic-graph-with-start-and-end-node/284769) question and its answers), thus $\Omega(2^n)$.

Comment: Please consider telling me what mistakes I've made in my reasoning, instead of simply downvoting. I think that everyone would benefit from this discussion.